# __mro__ attribute in class

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class C(object):
   pass

>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__mro__
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

Why does `C.__mro__` work and `c.__mro__` doesn't?

Comment: Because that's an attribute of `type`, which your instances aren't.

Comment: What jon said. But you can do `c.__class__.__mro__`.

Comment: ok. Thanks :-). Please refer me somewhere to read more about attribute of `type` because I know only "instance type" and "static type".

Comment: "Type" is similar to "class", but more primitive. So `int`, `str`, `tuple`, `list`etc, are types. See [Type Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#type-objects) and follow the links. In Python 3 the distinction between type and class is gone.